# mvn sonar:sonar throwing error

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, sonarqube

I'm using SONAR for my project. When I execute `mvn sonar:sonar` , it throws

`java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map in method`

This is after I update my JDK to 1.7.0_09 and maven to 3.0.4.

Please Help me.

Comment: Please supply us with more information. What is your `pom.xml` and especially Sonar configuration like?

Comment: I haven't configured any plugin for SONAR in project. configured maven plugin for test cases only. Do I need to add any plugin for that..?

Comment: You should give a try to another version of the JDK. This error has already been raised in some other projects, and each time it was due to a bug in the JDK.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Modified reverted my JDK to 1.6.0. It is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please configure server in your setting.xml of maven.

**Updated**

add In  your `setting.xml` of maven

```
<profile>
   <id>sonar</id>
   <activation>
      <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
   <properties>
      <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>
      <sonar.jdbc.driver>org.postgresql.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driver>
      <sonar.jdbc.username>user</sonar.jdbc.username>
      <sonar.jdbc.password>password</sonar.jdbc.password>
      <!-- SERVER ON A REMOTE HOST -->
      <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
   </properties>
</profile>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Rohit. May I know which server it is..? I have configured maven repo for jar files. For Sonar do we need do that.?

Comment: sonar will be your databse. Actually sonar create a databse to store its rules.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. Sonar maintains a database to monitor the changes between SNAPSHOT's. But is the error `java.lang.VerifyError` is because of that.? When it is executing fine against other modules.! I'm confused..

Comment: Adding to above, I have configured SONAR to execute for every change in code. Locally I'm unable to execute because of this error.